# how to resolve the type or namespace "HttpContextBase " could not be found in ASP.Net class library in a new class library i created

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

public class BasketService
    {
        IRepositoryBase baskets;

```
    public const string BasketSession = "eCommerceBasket";
    public BasketService(IRepositoryBase<Basket> baskets)
    {
        this.baskets = baskets;
    }
    private Basket CreateNewBasket(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added `using System.Web;` at the top of the file?

Comment: i created this project with this class and want to use it as a basket service in my mvc application instead of creating it in the mvc application.

Comment: Why would you make a basket depend on HttpContextBase? Seems like you need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** this is really what you want...

[The `HttpContextBase` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontextbase) is in the `System.Web` namespace.  So you'll either need to fully-qualify the class name:

```
private Basket CreateNewBasket(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
{

}
```

*or* add the appropriate [`using` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) at the top of your code file:

```
using System.Web;
```

If you then get an error that `HttpContextBase` isn't in that namespace or that the namespace doesn't exist, double-check that you've added the reference to your project.  In the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio, right-click on the "References" node in the project and select "Add Reference". Navigate to the "Assemblies" to find and select System.Web. Click "OK".

---

**Having said that...** Are you *sure* this is the design you want?  If your goal is to make a generic service which can be used by different applications, making that service *depend on the web application* would be ill-advised.  What happens if you want to use it in a Console Application?  There's no web context there.

Instead of making your general-purpose code depend on UI-specific things, turn that around.  Make your UI-specific applications depend on the general-purpose code.  So for this particular method, ask yourself...

> What would I need to "create" a new "basket"?

Whatever information that is, that's what `CreateNewBasket` should accept as parameters.  Maybe it's a handful of values, maybe it's a custom object, that's up to you.  But "creating a basket" does *not* require an HTTP context.  It requires some values that you are expecting to find in your HTTP context at a particular time.

The application layer should be responsible for pulling those values from the HTTP context and providing them to `CreateNewBasket`.  The general-purpose code should just require the values themselves.

Comment: Dave: really great thought 